# Typing Library in Processing

Tags: processing, paint

I was wondering if there was a library in Processing that would allow you to type and it would show up on the screen while a program was running. Or a way I could do this without a library. I am working on a paint like program and I want to allow the user to be able to hit t then click an area then type so they can add text to their picture. I can add things like text size and other things myself. Thanks in advance.
SnapDraggen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get user input (and judging by your other question, this is the case), then just use the `keyPressed()` function along with the `key` variable:

```
void draw(){
   rect(25, 25, 25, 25);
}

void keyPressed() {
   if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
   }
   else if (key == 'g' || key == 'G') {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
   }
   else if (key == 'b' || key == 'B') {
      fill(0, 0, 255);
   }
   else{
      fill(0);
   }
}
```

But if you want a component that you can type into, then either create your own (using the `keyPressed()` function to get input) or look into libraries such as [ControlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) or [G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/).